# Trouble Syncing Firebase Authentication with MongoDB in Next.js and Node.js-Express: New User Sign-In Issue

Tags: node.js, firebase, authentication, next.js, google-signin

I'm developing a web app using Next.js with a Node.js-Express backend and MongoDB, and I'm facing a challenge with user authentication using Firebase's signinwithpopup method.

Consider the following use case: a user on the login page, either new or not having created an account before, attempts to sign in using the 'Sign in with Google' button. The SDK initiates the sign-in process, checking if the user already exists on Firebase. If the user exists, it allows the sign-in; otherwise, it creates a new user on Firebase and authenticates them.

The issue arises when the app attempts to fetch user data from the database after the user is logged in. Despite successful Firebase authentication, the user does not exist in my MongoDB database. On my current implementation, the user data is reflected in my database when following the correct path, which is through completing the sign-up process.

```
import { UserAuth } from "../../utils/globalContexts/AuthContext";

//...

 const handleSignin = () => {
    console.log("Signing in with google")
    try {
      googleSignin()
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

// ... 

 <button
            onClick={handleSignin}
            className="bg-white text-gray-800 font-bold rounded-md px-3 py-3 border-2 border-gray-900/20 flex gap-2 w-full items-center justify-center cursor-pointer">
            <img src="/images/google.png" alt="google" className="h-5 w-5" />
            Google
          </button>
```

auth context

```
import { useContext, createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { signInWithPopup, signOut, onAuthStateChanged, GoogleAuthProvider, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth  } from "../../firebase";
import { User } from "firebase/auth";
import { FirebaseError } from "firebase/app";


interface AuthContextType {
    user: User
    googleSignin: () => void
    emailSignup: (email: string, password: string) => void
    emailSignin: (email: string, password: string) => void
    logOut: () => void
}

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>(null);

export const AuthContextProvider = (props: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    const emailSignup = async (email: string, password: string) => {
        try {
            await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        } catch (e) {
            if (e instanceof FirebaseError) {
                console.log(e.code)
                console.log(e.message)
            } else {
                console.log(e)
            }

        }  
    }

    const emailSignin = async (email: string, password: string) => {
        try {
            await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        } catch (e) {
            if (e instanceof FirebaseError) {
                console.log(e.code)
                console.log(e.message)
            } else {
                console.log(e)
            }

        }
    }

    const googleSignin = () => {
        const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

        try {
            signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
        
    }

    const logOut = () => {
        signOut(auth);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
            setUser(currentUser);
        });

        return () => unsubscribe()
    }, [user])

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, googleSignin, emailSignup, emailSignin, logOut}}>
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const UserAuth = () => {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

I'm seeking advice or a solution on how to handle this situation and ensure that user data is properly synchronized between Firebase and my MongoDB database. Any guidance or best practices would be greatly appreciated.